# Changing the style of a second division with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magento

I have a page in magento which has some dynamically created elements but the problem is the classes are named the same. I would like to change the styling of the second class but not the first.

How would I go about this? I was thinking possibly jQuery but wasn't 100% sure where I should be looking for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$(".YourClassName:nth-child(2)").css("PropertyToChange", "ValueOfProperty");
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/wp3Hd/) to illustrate.